# How MPLS solve the fragmentation problem?

Tags: mpls

MPLS appends a label for any packet enters its network. If a packet is equal to the maximum packet size, then packet may get fragmented after appending the label. How does MPLS solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPLS has no inherent method for solving this problem.  Cisco routers (running MPLS) will remove the labels, fragment the packet, then reapply the labels to the fragments.

Fragmentation can be avoided by using Path MTU Discovery, or by using the Cisco `mpls mtu` command.